# Glassfish webapp with maven system dependency

Tags: maven, web-applications, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have a collaborative project that is a webapp being deployed to a Glassfish installation.

The project depends on an external dependency. This dependency is a system level dependency for the following reasons

1. Using mvn install isn't workable as it's a collaborative project
2. We don't have access to a shared repository manager such as Nexus

So I am attempting to run the webapp on Glassfish via eclipse, during the start up of Glassfish I see the following messages

> 2015-12-01T15:39:20.518+0000|Info: WELD-000119: Not generating any
>   bean definitions from uk.xxx.AppProducer because of underlying class
>   loading error: Type uk.xxx.dao.CouchbaseFormDAO not found.  If this is
>   unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
>   2015-12-01T15:39:20.590+0000|Info: WELD-000119: Not generating any
>   bean definitions from uk.xxx.controller.FormController because of
>   underlying class loading error: Type
>   uk.xxx.service.CouchbaseServiceException not found.  If this is
>   unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error. 2

These missing classes are part of this maven system dependency. Is there some additional maven plugin configuration I need to do?

I have the following in my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>data-access</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.build.directory}/../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/data-access.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

As well as these plugins

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```